# selecting a font from the font-family in css

Tags: css, firefox, font-family

It's supposed that the font-family holds several font names for those times that the browser doesn't support the first one. it check the second font name and so on.

I have a desire font and I put it as a first font in the list, but my mozilla browser picks up another font and doesn't recognise my desire font .However when I clear the rest of the fonts. The browser recognise my desire font and apply it in my site .

(I have test this situation in firebug by just temporary changing the style )

How can I find where does this problem come from?

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using to achieve what you what?

Comment: Without code or example or whatsoever it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @LinkinTED Impossibru!!!! Also yeah, we would need to see some code otherwise its just us guessing and confusing you.

Comment: @Chandranshu Clearly you have never used the internet. [Look here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-EHK6TZk7VHY/UBzLvk-kYaI/AAAAAAAAARw/i1WARiEDAF0/s1600/1339174789948.jpg) and then you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN page on font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family),

> When a font is only available in some styles, variants, or sizes,
>   those properties may also influence which font family is chosen.

For a more detailed understanding of how font-family selection works, please read [W3C's rules of font style matchin](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-style-matching).

Your first font is only available in a few particular variations and which is why it's ignored when other more complete fonts are present. In absence of other options, FF has to use whatever is available.